# Merging two table data in Oracle - Column Wise

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two SQL queries to extract data as per Tables shown below:

====

Query to get table A:

```
SELECT :DATE AS Date, A.Tracking_ID AS Number, A.Country, COUNT(EmailID) AS EmailSent
FROM
FACT_EMAILS A
LEFT OUTER JOIN DIM_ACCOUNT B
ON A.ACCT_ID=B.ACCT_ID
WHERE A.TIMESTAMP>SYSDATE
AND A.Tracking_ID IN (‘12345’,’23416’,’7890’)
GROUP BY :DATE, A.Tracking_ID, A.Country
```

Query to get Table B:

```
SELECT :DATE AS Date, A.Tracking_ID AS Number, A.Country, COUNT(EmailID) AS EmailResponse
FROM
FACT_EMAILS A
LEFT OUTER JOIN DIM_ACCOUNT B
ON A.ACCT_ID=B.ACCT_ID
INNER JOIN DIM_EMAILRESP C
ON C.Email_Type_ID = A.Email_Type_ID
WHERE C.Email_Type_ID IN (1,3,5)
AND A.TIMESTAMP>SYSDATE
AND A.Tracking_ID IN (‘12345’,’23416’,’7890’,)
GROUP BY :DATE, A.Tracking_ID, A.Country
```

======

Background: There is one extra table that I make use of to get the output I am getting in Table B as I am looking only for records where there is a email response. This table is not being used when I am extracting the data in Table A. Also there is no table A and table B in database. The naming is just used to describe this example.

My question here is how do I combine both Table A, Table B and get output as Table C.

[image: Table A]

[image: Table B]

[image: Table C (Output)]

Can someone please help.

Comment: Hint:  `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: HI Gordon, I am performing some aggregation (Count operation to get the count of total email sent and email responses) to retrieve data in my source tables. How do I go about doing a left join here?

Comment: Unless you provide the `queries` that you need help with, the best answer has already been provided to you (by @GordonLinoff).

Comment: Hi Peter, have edited my question with the queries. Could you please help

Comment: I would have thought that an email response (record in `DIM_EMAILRESP`) refers to a sent email (record in `FACT_EMAILS`), but this doesn't seem to be the case, because you don't join on `EmailID`, but only on `Email_Type_ID`. But this doesn't seem to make much sense. Please clarify. How are the tables related? What are their primary and foreign keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's just take your table A and table B data blocks and join them together:

```
SELECT 
  a.date, 
  a.number, 
  a.country, 
  a.EmailSent, 
  COALESCE(b.EmailResponse,0) as EmailResponse 
FROM
(
 SELECT :DATE AS Date, A.Tracking_ID AS Number, A.Country, COUNT(EmailID) AS 
 EmailSent
 FROM
 FACT_EMAILS A
 LEFT OUTER JOIN DIM_ACCOUNT B
 ON A.ACCT_ID=B.ACCT_ID
 WHERE A.TIMESTAMP>SYSDATE
 AND A.Tracking_ID IN ('12345','23416','7890')
 GROUP BY :DATE, A.Tracking_ID, A.Country
) a

LEFT OUTER JOIN

(    
 SELECT :DATE AS Date, A.Tracking_ID AS Number, A.Country, COUNT(EmailID) AS 
 EmailResponse
 FROM
 FACT_EMAILS A
 LEFT OUTER JOIN DIM_ACCOUNT B
 ON A.ACCT_ID=B.ACCT_ID
 INNER JOIN DIM_EMAILRESP C
 ON C.Email_Type_ID = A.Email_Type_ID
 WHERE C.Email_Type_ID IN (1,3,5)
 AND A.TIMESTAMP>SYSDATE
 AND A.Tracking_ID IN ('12345','23416','7890')
 GROUP BY :DATE, A.Tracking_ID, A.Country

) b
ON
 a.date = b.date AND
 a.Number = b.number AND
 a.country = b.country
```

Everything inside `(...) a` is your query that generated A

Everything inside `(...) b` is your query that generated B

The two are left joined on the common columns. `COALESCE` is used to put a 0 wherever there is no matching row data in B for `EmailsResponse`. I've corrected your wonky apostrophes in the `IN` clause

Realistically this could probably be solved by the much simpler query:

```
SELECT 
 :DATE AS Date, 
 A.Tracking_ID AS Number,
 A.Country,
 COUNT(A.Tracking_ID) as EmailSent,
 COUNT(C.Email_Type_ID) AS EmailResponse
FROM
 FACT_EMAILS A
 LEFT OUTER JOIN DIM_EMAILRESP C
 ON C.Email_Type_ID = A.Email_Type_ID
 AND C.Email_Type_ID IN (1,3,5)

WHEREA.TIMESTAMP>SYSDATE
 AND A.Tracking_ID IN ('12345','23416','7890')
 GROUP BY :DATE, A.Tracking_ID, A.Country
```

You didn't post all your table structures/relationships so I've had to guess at some things; like I'm guessing that B was unneeded in the query - it didn't seem to be used

Comment: Hi Caius..thanks for this. but when I tried this it doesn't give me the EmailSent column. it just gives me EmailResponse in my output. I am looking for both these columns as per my expected output in my question.

Comment: Ignore. I just figured that out. Thanks a lot Caius :)